# Is a rubber keyboard suitable for heavy use?

Tags: keyboard, review

Every keyboard wears out with time, and mine has some age already. The day it fails is coming closer and closer.

So I'm slowly starting to look around for a new one. I use the keyboard for gaming and programming, so it gets some pretty solid use. I also tend to eat by the computer, so there's plenty of... uhh... lifeforms down there.

Anyway, I was looking at these rubber keyboards. They come pretty cheap (my local computer shop has one for less than $20) and they seem to have some nice properties. They can be easily cleaned, they're quiet, and can be rolled up when needed (plus no worries about spilled drinks).

However I'm wondering what their type-ability is. If I can't write on it at a decent speed, the rest of the features don't matter. Not that I'm a fast typer, but being a professional progammer does give a boost to the skill.

I couldn't find any reviews on the net so I'm turning to you. Who has used these keyboards and what was your experience? Perhaps there is something else I haven't though of why such a keyboard would not be a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was once optimistic about them for the reasons you listed, but found them to be absolutely horrible in use. The keys quite literally wobble back and forth on their downward stroke, so unless you enjoy battling little mounds of jelly, avoid.

You should go to a hardware outlet and give it a shot. I really can't recommend the things for anybody. I think typing would be marginally faster than an on-screen keyboard.

There are probably no reviews because the things cost a few bucks and nobody loves them enough to express it on a review site. Simply another buck or two thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

I have one, and the issue is that you need a flat surface for it to lie on, otherwise it is impossible to do any decent typing.

Actually, it is impossible to type anyway...I wouldn't even wish this keyboard upon my worst enemy.